# How do I find which program is disabling the screensaver?

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I was running a program that disables the Windows screensaver.  I'm not sure what program it was, but the screensaver will not work even when all programs are closed.  I have to restart Windows to make it work again.

How do I find which program is disabling the screensaver?

More information:

- The programs were closed properly and did not crash on closing.
- When I open either Windows Media Player 12 or Windows Media Player Classic by K-Lite and close it, the screensaver becomes disabled and will not work until I restart the computer.

Comment: Which programs run in the background? Did a program that you closed crash on closing (happens frequently on some software)? You can check this via TaskManager.

Comment: no, it's not crash on closing.

it real closed and not appears in task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might have a codec that is not releasing it's hold once you close you media player. I'd narrow it down to which codec is being loaded, and try disabling it and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, then find a suitable analog for that particular codec and you should be fine.

I've had issues with k-lite codec pack in the past, especially if you choose the "Mega Version" or whichever one installs a ton of codecs. Most users can get by with the smallest one just fine.

Comment: Yes, it's because some codec that is not releasing when I close media player, but I don't know what codec is it and don't know how to end task it because it had only media player classic file executed in task manager.

Comment: You'd have to use the codec manager that comes with Klite and disable them one at a time. Most of the time, you can see which codecs are required to play a file by right-click>properties on the video file. See which ones are being used and disable them(or ones similarly named). You should be able to narrow it down pretty quickly.